# Are there synonyms for the collocation 'take video'?

Tags: synonyms

Are there synonyms for the collocation '**take video**'?

For example:

> He wanted to take a video of this scene, but then his battery died.

I'm looking for other ways to express while talking about **talking videos**. Are there such ways?What about **record** video, is idiomatic?

I checked the dictionary ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=take%20video), [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=TAKE%20VIDEO)) but I didn't find an answer.

Comment: The one-word verb for ***taking / recording / shooting video*** is just ***film***, as in *Observers **filmed** the riots.* The corresponding verb (formed in the same way) for *recording **audio*** is ***tape***, but that can sometimes imply both audio and video.

Comment: "to take video" is not idiomatic. We cannot give a synonym for an incorrect phrase. Please provide a complete sentence using the phrase. That will give us some context for your question.

Comment: Honestly. I'm surprised. I thought it is. Probably I was confused with taking photos. I added a context to my question.

Comment: I found that this taking video is in usage among native English speakers... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC5qrJjgLfM

Comment: Business Insider's YouTube channel is not concerned with English grammar.  The person who uploaded that video is using non-standard English (and who cares, in this context) but it would not be accepted in serious print media.

Comment: Ok, see this one. 
https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=COAWBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA207&dq=%22taking+videos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjiyYvI8f_pAhXuiIsKHf09DiEQ6AEIXjAG#v=onepage&q=%22taking%20videos%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have never encountered take video.  I believe that to shoot video or shooting a video is the most idiomatic expression.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK we'd say, "He wanted to video the scene". [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/video) says it is a British usage.

Professionals here may, nowadays, call the process 'shooting a video' or possibly 'filming', but at TV companies a clear distinction used to be made between filming and videoing because you didn't film on video tape and you didn't video on film.

I've never heard 'take a video.'